# Angular Material placeholder label not animating when typing in form field

Tags: angular-material, angular5

I'm using Angular Material. I'm not able to see my placeholder label (which is supposed to move to the top) once I start typing something in the form field.

Here's my code:

```html
 <mat-card-content>
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Username" value="" class="form-control"
               formControlName="username" required>
      </mat-form-field>
</mat-car-content>
```

`package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "inflight": "^1.0.6",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
```

[image: Screenshot of overlay]

Comment: Hello. Could you manage to provide a plunckr or similar? Because the problem is obviously not in your html. Maybe in your css, this class "form-control"?
Also, have you tried on another browser?

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted? I am facing the same issue this morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue and resolved it by using a pre-built theme by updating the `styles.css` file with:

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

[Theming Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)
[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52242814/angular-6-material-text-box-floating-placeholder-not-working)