# Angular 6 - Material Text box Floating placeholder not working

Tags: textbox, angular-material

I want to use Angular 6 Material UI componenet to give more advance look and feel, I am running below test program , but matInput is not giving that look and feel.
Reference: https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview
Code:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <md-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input mdInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
  </md-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

and my pachage.json is

```
{
  "name": "employee-management-system",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/common": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/core": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/forms": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/http": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/router": "6.1.7",
    "core-js": "2.5.7",
    "rxjs": "6.3.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26",
    "moment": "2.22.2",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "6.4.7",
    "@angular/material": "6.4.7",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.5.4",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "6.4.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

Output:

[place holder is not floating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q0Dq.png)

Answer (score 2):

You have to include a theme in your angular material application. You can use one of the pre-built themes, to do that add in your `styles.css`:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

You can change this theme for other of the prebuilt themes:

```
indigo-pink.css
pink-bluegrey.css
purple-green.css
```

or make your own theme.